# Eurekaで起こるメモリリークについて

Tags: swift, メモリ管理

swiftでEurekaという設定画面を作るライブラリを使用してみたのですが、簡単なサンプルコードを実行した際にメモリリークが起きてしまいました。

ビルドをした段階ではメモリリークは起きていませんが、textRowやtextAreaRowに文字を入力するとUiDelayedActionでメモリリークが発生していました。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/ios-memory-leak-check-and-prevent-190508/
こちらのWEBサイトを参考にして「XCODEでメモリリークをチェックしよう」の部分を参照して調べたところ、UIDelayedActionの欄にメモリリークのマークがあって判断しました。

原因について教えていただけないでしょうか。

swift初学者のため初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

```swift
import UIKit
import Eureka

class ViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
            form
                +++ Section("セクション1")
                    <<< TextRow { row in
                        row.title = "タイトル"
                        row.placeholder = "タイトルを入力"
                      }
                    <<< TextAreaRow { row in
                        row.placeholder = "メモを入力"
              }
              +++ Section("セクション2")
                    <<< TextRow { row in
                        row.title = "メモ"
                        row.placeholder = "メモを入力"
                    }

    }

}
```

Comment: 「UiDelayedActionでメモリリークが発生」を、どのようにして検出されたのですか？

Comment: https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/ios-memory-leak-check-and-prevent-190508/　これの「XCODEでメモリリークをチェックしよう」の部分を参照して調べたところ、UIDelayedActionの欄にメモリリークのマークがあって判断しました！

Comment: リンク先の記事に記載されているのは「循環参照」を確認する方法ですね。一時的に循環参照ができても、メモリリークにはつながらないこともあります。Instruments のLeaksは試してみましたか?

Comment: このようなツールがあったのですね。。leaksでも調べたところUIDelayedActionでメモリリークが発生してました。。